# Odd for-loop behavior

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Running Windows 7 Enterprise on a 64-bit Dell laptop (standard specs), and trying to put together a simple batch script.

I'm at a loss to figure out what's going on with the loop below.

I want to loop through a set of date ranges listed in a text file called "ContactUsDates.txt", formatted like this:

2014-02-26,2014-02-27

2014-02-27,2014-02-28

2014-02-28,2014-03-01

etc... date before the comma would be the start date, date after the comma would be the end date. Filename is a pared-down version of the start date.

I want my output to look like this:

Start Date = 2014-02-26

End Date = 2014-02-27

Filename = 140226

---

Start Date = 2014-02-27

End Date = 2014-02-28

Filename = 140227

---

Start Date = 2014-02-28

End Date = 2014-02-29

Filename = 140228

---

etc...

This is the code I'm currently running:

```
@echo OFF

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%A in (ContactUsDates.txt) do (

set daterange=%%A

set startdate=!daterange:~0,10!
set enddate=!daterange:~11,10!
set filename=!daterange:~2,2!!daterange:~5,2!!daterange:~8,2!


@echo Start Date = %startdate%
@echo End Date = %enddate% 
@echo Filename = %filename%

@echo --------------

)
```

The output I get is sometimes blank:

Start Date =

End Date =

Filename =

---

Start Date =

End Date =

Filename =

---

But sometimes I get the start date and end date, but not the filename:

Start Date = 2014-02-26

End Date = 2014-02-27

Filename =

---

Start Date = 2014-02-27

End Date = 2014-02-28

Filename =

---

This is the identical code run in 2 different command shells.

Any help to figure out what might be going on would be much appreciated!

Comment: I doubt it is a 'dos batchfile'. `DOS` is an operating system that hasn't been in use since after Windows ME.

Comment: Your code will work as written if you replace the `%` in the `echo` statements with `!`.  But it is more effective to split the data into two variables using the `"tokens=1,2* delims=,"` in the `for` statement.  See my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I still call anything run in a CMD window "dos" :) I don't program or know much about these things, so just doing my best!

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it.  Try this:

```
@echo OFF

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%A in (ContactUsDates.txt) do (

set startdate=%%A
set enddate=%%B
set filename=!startdate:-=!
set filename=!filename:~2!

echo Start Date = !startdate!
echo End Date = !enddate! 
echo Filename = !filename!

echo --------------

)

endlocal
```

When I run it, the output looks like this:

```
Start Date = 2014-02-26
End Date = 2014-02-27
Filename = 140226
--------------
Start Date = 2014-02-27
End Date = 2014-02-28
Filename = 140227
--------------
Start Date = 2014-02-28
End Date = 2014-03-01
Filename = 140228
--------------
```

Comment: I was almost finished writing exactly the same code ^^

Comment: Thanks, that runs perfectly :) And I now have more cool tools like "tokens" and "delims".